# How to access value 0 of json data (react-native) expo

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have some json data such as:

```
[{"timestamp":"2020-03-23T14:00:00.000Z","symbol":"AAL","name":"American Airlines Group","industry":"Industrials","open":10.9,"high":11.36,"low":10.01,"close":10.25,"volumes":55494100},

{"timestamp":"2020-03-22T14:00:00.000Z","symbol":"AAL","name":"American Airlines Group","industry":"Industrials","open":10.6526,"high":12,"low":10.3,"close":10.38,"volumes":62681800},


{"timestamp":"2020-03-19T14:00:00.000Z","symbol":"AAL","name":"American Airlines Group","industry":"Industrials","open":11.6,"high":12.16,"low":10.01,"close":10.29,"volumes":71584500},{"timestamp":"2020-03-18T14:00:00.000Z","symbol":"AAL","name":"American Airlines
```

I want to get only the 0 index value:

```
This one:   [{"timestamp":"2020-03-23T14:00:00.000Z","symbol":"AAL","name":"American Airlines Group","industry":"Industrials","open":10.9,"high":11.36,"low":10.01,"close":10.25,"volumes":55494100},{"timestamp":"2020-03-22T14:00:00.000Z",
```

My code:

```
  let movies = state.myListData.map((val) => {
    return (
      <View key={val.symbol} style={styles.text}>
        <Text style={styles.text} key={val.symbol}>
          {val.high}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.text} key={val.symbol}>
          {val.close}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  });
```

Right now I am getting all the values, but how can I get only the value 0? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: use `Array.splice()` method

Comment: Can you tell me where to write that in my code? I didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do this:

```js
let item = state.myListData[0];
let movie = (
  <View key={item.symbol} style={styles.text}>
    <Text style={styles.text} key={item.symbol}>
      {item.high}
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.text} key={item.symbol}>
      {item.close}
    </Text>
  </View>
)
```

Comment: If I write this it says its undefined
let item = state.myListData[0];

Comment: But if I print state.myListData it prints all the values.That's my json data if that helps: `Object {
  "close": 63.37,
  "high": 67.5599,
  "industry": "Health Care",
  "low": 62.09,
  "name": "Agilent Technologies Inc",
  "open": 66.8,
  "symbol": "A",
  "timestamp": "2020-03-23T14:00:00.000Z",
  "volumes": 2989560,
}
Object {
  "close": 63.37,
  "high": 67.5599,
  "industry": "Health Care",
  "low": 62.09,
  "name": "Agilent Technologies Inc",
  "open": 66.8,
  "symbol": "A",
  "timestamp": "2020-03-23T14:00:00.000Z",
  "volumes": 2989560,
}`